# Issues with $scope while testing

Tags: angularjs, phantomjs, karma-jasmine, karma-mocha

I am using a controller in my angular app in which I am not passing "$scope" as the argument in this line:

```
angular.module('module').controller('MyCtrl',function() {var myCtrl = this; myCtrl.bookingId = 1}
```

The problem is that all the tests on jasmine that I have seen on line use "$scope" for testing. For example,

```
expect($scope.bookingId).toEqual(1);
```

but I can't use scope because I have not been using it in my Controller. How can I check the value of bookingId using expect? Please help me in this regard.

/*Edit For More Clarification*/

This is my controller:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('MyCtrl',
['MyService', '$window', '$timeout', function(MySrv, $window, $timeout) {
    var MyCtrl= this
    MyCtrl.bookingId = 0;
```

And this is my Test:

```
describe('MyCtrlTest', function () {

beforeEach(module('myModule'));
//beforeEach(angular.mock.module('myModule'));
var $controller,  $_jspBookingUid, MyServiceMock, $scope, $ctrl;

beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, $rootScope, _$jspBookingUid_){
    $controller = _$controller_;
    $_jspBookingUid = _$jspBookingUid_;
    MyServiceMock = {
        getBookingId: function(){

        }

    };
    spyOn(MyServiceMock, 'getBookingId').and.returnValue(1);

    //$scope = $rootScope.$new();

    $ctrl = $controller('MyCtrl', {MyService: MyServiceMock});
}));

it('should call MyService.getBookingId() once', function() {
    expect(MyServiceMock.getBookingId).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(MyServiceMock.getBookingId.calls.count()).toEqual(1);
});

it('should attach bookingId to the scope(Controller)', function() {
    expect($ctrl.bookingId).toEqual(1);
});
```

});

Comment: use the controller as name in your test: `expect($scope.ctrlAsName.bookingId).toEqual(1)`

Comment: I am sorry but it does not seem to be working. Now I am getting 
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$scope.ctrlAsName')

Comment: This will work only for controllerAs syntax, i.e. `$controller('MyCtrl as ctrlAsName', { $scope: ... })`

Answer (score 0):

`$controller` service returns a new controller instance. And it would be

```
var ctrl = $controller('MyCtrl');
expect(ctrl.bookingId).toEqual(1);
```

Comment: Does not seem to be working for me, I have updated my original question details, please have a look at it.

Comment: And what happens then? The controller doesn't call getBookingId in your code.

Comment: no the same error occours: 
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating '$ctrl.bookingId')

Comment: I suggest to check for errors and to debug how controller constructor runs. If $controller() is performed successfully, it shouldn't return undefined.